# Does flipping the negative in a fraction flip all terms both sides?

Tags: fractions

This is an expression that contains a negative in the denominator. If I were to take the negative and place it in the numerator, would this change all positive terms to negative and vice-versa?

Negative in denominator: 
$\frac{a+3-y^2}{-2}$

After flipping negative to the numerator: $\frac{-a-3+y^2}{2}$ (Is this correct?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiplying numerator and denominator with $(-1)$ we get
$$\frac{-a-3+y^2}{2}$$

Comment: Is this a method we can use to take negatives out of a denominator?

Comment: yes this is the general method

Answer (score 1):

This is not an equation. Rather, this is an expression. For the change, multiply both the numerator and the denominator by -1.

Comment: Will edit, thanks.

Comment: May I kindly know the reason behind downvoting?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but your language is a little vague and misleading.  Things to notice:

$1/1 = 1$  (Duh)

$1/(-1) = -1$ (Not so duh; but pretty easy)

$1*1 = 1; (-1)*1= 1*(-1) = -1; (-1)(-1) = 1$  ("A negative times a negative is a positive".  To some this is obvious; to some this makes no sense.  But most know this as a rule [$*$])

$a(b + c) = ac + ac$ (this is the distributive law)

So if we know all those thing we can conclude:

$\frac {a + 3 - y^2}{-2} = $

$\frac{a+3 - y^2}{(-1)2}=$

$\frac 1{-1}\frac{a+3 -y^2}{2} =$

$- \frac{a+3 -y^2}{2} =$

$\frac{(-1)(a+3-y^2)}2 =$

$\frac{(-1)a + (-1)3 -(-1)y^2}2=$

$\frac{-a -3 +y^2}2$

which can be simplified as "you flip the sign everywhere".

Post-script:  Or, d'oh, we can do what everyone else suggests:

$\frac {a + 3 - y^2}{-2} = 1*\frac {a + 3 - y^2}{-2}=\frac{-1}{-1}\frac {a + 3 - y^2}{-2}= \frac{-(a+3-y^2}{-(-2)} = \frac {-a - 3 + y^2}{2}$

=====

[$*$] why is "a negative times a negative a positive"

Welp.... if $x = -5$ means $5 + x = 0$ and $3*5$ means $5+5+5$.  So $(-3)*5= x$ means $x + 5+5+5 = 0$ so $(-3)*5 = -5 -5 -5$.  So $(-3)*(-5) = -(5) -(-5) - (-5) = 5+5+5 = 3*5$.

Comment: I see, where I put the negative on the fraction just manipulates the terms, but outputs the same result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

yes it's like if you put parentheses in the numerator and u replace whats inside by a letter or a number. So u would have to ditribute the negative sign to every term inside the parentheses.
$\frac{-(a+3-y^3)}{2}$